# Cargar campos de un form con elementos de un array

Tags: php, array, formularios

Hola tengo el siguiente problema:

En la variable $_SESSION[‘DETALLE’] tengo datos de un producto y tengo que enviarlos en un formulario

```
foreach ($_SESSION['DETALLE'] as $indice => $prod) {
    $transaccion_item = $prod['COMPROBANTE'];
    $transaccion_priceitem = $prod['IMPORTE'];
}

<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="PAGAR">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="Producto[]" id="producto1" value="<?= $transaccion_item ?>" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="MontoProducto[]" id="montoproducto1" value="<?= $transaccion_priceitem ?>" /><br />
</form>
```

El formulario solo muestra el ultimo elemento en los input $transaccion_item y en $transaccion_priceitem pero como esto es dinámico a veces hay solo un elemento y está todo ok pero otras veces tengo 2 o mas comprobantes e importes

Comment: Observa que el html del formulario esta fuera del ciclo de los productos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo utilizas el bucle `foreach` para asignar un valor a `$transaccion_item` y `$transaccion_priceitem`. Eso únicamente hace que en cada iteración sobrescriba el valor de ambas variables, de ahí que solo muestre un elemento.

Debes incluir el bucle dentro del formulario, generando dos campos nuevos con los valores del comprobante y el importe en cada iteración.

Además, para no repetir el valor en la propiedad `id` de los inputs, añade una variable fuera del bucle (`$counter = 1`) que vaya aumentando dentro de él (`$counter++`). De este modo, las ids de los distintos comprobantes serán *producto1*, *producto2*, etc.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="PAGAR">
    </div>
    <?php $counter = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['DETALLE'] as $indice => $prod) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="Producto[]" id="producto<?= $counter ?>" value="<?= $prod['COMPROBANTE'] ?>" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="MontoProducto[]" id="montoproducto<?= $counter ?>" value="<?= $prod['IMPORTE'] ?>" /><br />
    <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar todos los productos en el formulario, debes utilizar un ciclo `foreach` dentro del formulario y crear inputs dinámicos para cada producto

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="PAGAR">
    </div>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['DETALLE'] as $indice => $prod) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="Producto[]" id="producto<?= $indice + 1 ?>" value="<?= $prod['COMPROBANTE'] ?>" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="MontoProducto[]" id="montoproducto<?= $indice + 1 ?>" value="<?= $prod['IMPORTE'] ?>" /><br />
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

En este ejemplo, utilizamos un ciclo `foreach` para recorrer cada producto en la variable `$_SESSION['DETALLE']` y crear inputs dinámicos para cada producto. La variable `$indice` se utiliza para crear identificadores únicos para cada input.